# DRY when make targets can be built from different source file extensions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm building .js files from .ts and .tsx files. They're built in exactly the same way and ideally I don't want to repeat a rule. Right now, the following works:

```
$(out)/%.js: %.ts
    @mkdir --parents $(@D)
    BABEL_ENV=node babel $(<) --out-file $(@) --source-maps

$(out)/%.js: %.tsx
    @mkdir --parents $(@D)
    BABEL_ENV=node babel $(<) --out-file $(@) --source-maps
```

Is there a way to tell make to look for either a .ts or a .tsx in the prerequisites list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

You can reduce your repeating a little bit by putting the recipe into a variable:

```
define BUILD_JS
@mkdir --parents $(@D)
BABEL_ENV=node babel $(<) --out-file $(@) --source-maps
endif

$(out)/%.js: %.ts
        $(BUILD_JS)

$(out)/%.js: %.tsx
        $(BUILD_JS)
```